# Available Functions on FMS Server

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-media-server, fms3

I have a chat client that uses FMS server. I do not know how many more functions are on FSM that I can utilize. There is 0 documentation for the available FMS server. Is there a way to browse or query all the available features/functions of Adobe FMS server?

Also some of the chatters crashes my flash play remotely. I think, they are just overflowing the buffer? Is it the case? or how anyone can remotely crash my flash player? This only happens if I kick any of the specific user using the command /kick user.

Answer (score 0):

FMS has pretty good doc at [FMS API](http://help.adobe.com/en%5fUS/FlashMediaServer/3.5%5fSS%5fASD/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d11a11aff5ba-7f8b.html). But functions you want depend of who implemented server side for you.

Crash might be caused of your chat implementation. You need to find initial developer to fix that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I just have a client. I want to know which features/functions the remote FMS offers. so, I can implement them in the client.